# libtiff error: Old-style JPEG compression support is not configured

Tags: c, macos, tiff, bmp, libtiff

While converting TIFF to BMP using libtiff on Mac OS X, I got these errors:

```
scannerdata.tif: Old-style JPEG compression support is not configured.

scannerdata.tif: Sorry, requested compression method is not configured.
```

I am currently using libtiff in Mac OS X.

My implementation of tiff to bmp:

```
static void tifftobmp(char *colorMode){

    DBG(1, ">> tifftobmp \n");

    /* For files and file header */
    char infile[PATH_MAX] = {0};
    char outfile[PATH_MAX] = {0};
    char tempfile[PATH_MAX] = {0};
    TIFF *tifFile;
    FILE *bmpFile, *tmpBitmapFile;
    uint32 image_width, image_height, long_val, short_val;

    /* For Colour table */
    unsigned char padding;
    unsigned short i;
    unsigned char value;

    /* For image information */
    Image_Information *image_info;
    image_info = (Image_Information *)malloc(sizeof(Image_Information));

    sprintf(infile, TIFF_IMAGE_DATA);
    sprintf(outfile, BMP_IMAGE_DATA);
    sprintf(tempfile, TEMP_IMAGE_DATA);

    /* Open necessary files */
    tifFile = TIFFOpen(infile, "r");
    if (!tifFile){
        DBG(128, "Can't open %s for reading\n", infile);
        TIFFClose(tifFile);
    }

    bmpFile = fopen(outfile, "wb");
    if (!bmpFile){
        DBG(128, "Can't open %s for writing\n", outfile);
        fclose(bmpFile);
    }

    tmpBitmapFile = fopen(tempfile, "wb");
    if (!tmpBitmapFile){
        DBG(128, "Can't open %s for writing\n", tempfile);
        fclose(tmpBitmapFile);
    }

    TIFFGetField(tifFile, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, &image_height);
    TIFFGetField(tifFile, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, &image_width);

    image_info->img_height = image_height;
    image_info->img_width = image_width;

    /* Get Image Info Color */
    if(strcmp(colorMode,"COLOR") == 0){
        get_image_info_color(image_info);

    }else if (strcmp(colorMode,"GRAY") == 0){
        get_image_info_gray(image_info);

    }else if(strcmp(colorMode,"MONO") == 0){
        get_image_info_mono(image_info);

    }

    /* Set Header */
    fwrite("BM", 1, 2, bmpFile);        /* Signature */

    long_val = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)  + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + image_info->img_scansize * image_info->img_height;
    fwrite(&long_val, 4, 1, bmpFile);   /* Size in bytes of the bitmap file */

    short_val = 0;
    fwrite(&short_val, 2, 1, bmpFile);  /* Reserved, set as 0 */
    fwrite(&short_val, 2, 1, bmpFile);  /* Reserved, set as 0 */

    if(strcmp(colorMode,"COLOR") == 0){ /* Offset of the image from file start */
        long_val = 54;

    }else{
        long_val = 54 + (4 * (1 << image_info->img_bits_per_pixel));
    }
    fwrite(&long_val, 4, 1, bmpFile);

    long_val = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);  /* Size of BMPInfoHeader structure */
    fwrite(&long_val, 4, 1, bmpFile);
    fwrite(&image_info->img_width, 4, 1, bmpFile);
    fwrite(&image_info->img_height, 4, 1, bmpFile);

    short_val = 1;                  /* Number of image planes */
    fwrite(&short_val, 2, 1, bmpFile);

    if(strcmp(colorMode,"MONO") == 0){ /* Number of bits per pixel */
        short_val = image_info->img_bits_per_pixel;

    }else if (strcmp(colorMode,"COLOR") == 0){
        short_val = image_info->img_bits_per_pixel;

    }else if (strcmp(colorMode,"GRAY") == 0){
        short_val = image_info->img_bits_per_pixel;

    }
    fwrite(&short_val, 2, 1, bmpFile);
    long_val = 0;                   /* Compression method */
    fwrite(&long_val, 4, 1, bmpFile);
    long_val = 0;                   /* Size of uncompressed image in bytes */
    fwrite(&long_val, 4, 1, bmpFile);
    long_val = 0;                   /* X resolution, pixels per meter */
    fwrite(&long_val, 4, 1, bmpFile);
    long_val = 0;                   /* Y resolution, pixels per meter */
    fwrite(&long_val, 4, 1, bmpFile);

    if(strcmp(colorMode,"COLOR") == 0){  /* Size of colour table */
        long_val = 0;

    }else{
        long_val = 1 << image_info->img_bits_per_pixel;

    }
    fwrite(&long_val, 4, 1, bmpFile);

    long_val = 0;                   /* Number of important colours */
    fwrite(&long_val, 4, 1, bmpFile);

    /* Colour table */
    if(strcmp(colorMode,"MONO") == 0){
        value = 0xFF;
        padding = 0;

        /* white */
        fwrite(&value, 1, 1, bmpFile); /* R component */
        fwrite(&value, 1, 1, bmpFile); /* G component */
        fwrite(&value, 1, 1, bmpFile); /* B component */
        fwrite(&padding, 1, 1, bmpFile); /* padding */

        /* black */
        value = 0x00;
        fwrite(&value, 1, 1, bmpFile); /* R component */
        fwrite(&value, 1, 1, bmpFile); /* G component */
        fwrite(&value, 1, 1, bmpFile); /* B component */
        fwrite(&padding, 1, 1, bmpFile); /* padding */

    }else if (strcmp(colorMode,"GRAY") == 0){
        padding = 0;

        for ( i = 0; i <= 255; i++ ){
            fwrite(&i, 1, 1, bmpFile); /* R component */
            fwrite(&i, 1, 1, bmpFile); /* G component */
            fwrite(&i, 1, 1, bmpFile); /* B component */
            fwrite(&padding, 1, 1, bmpFile); /* padding */
        }

    }

    /* Read and write image */
    if(strcmp(colorMode,"MONO") == 0){
        read_mono_image(tifFile, tmpBitmapFile, image_info);

    }else if(strcmp(colorMode,"GRAY") == 0){
        read_gray_image(tifFile, tmpBitmapFile, image_info);

    }else if(strcmp(colorMode,"COLOR") == 0){
        read_color_image(tifFile, bmpFile, image_info);
    }

    if(strcmp(colorMode,"COLOR") != 0){
        fclose(tmpBitmapFile);
        flip_image(image_info, bmpFile);
    }

    fclose(bmpFile);
    TIFFClose(tifFile);

    DBG(1, "<< tifftobmp \n");

}
```

Comment: I guess your code is OK, but not relevant as it seems the files you are attempting to convert are not supported by Apple's version of libtiff.  One option is to install Macports and install `tiff` using that and then compile against `/opt/local/lib/libtiff.a` statically (probably using *Other linker flags* Xcode setting).   If that doesn't work then you'd have to compile `libtiff` yourself.

Comment: @trojanfoe I currently have usr/local/lib/libtiff.5.dylib

Comment: @trojanfoe is this the right command to install libtiff?

sudo port install lcms - Install lcms . This will also install jpeg, zlib, tiff

Comment: Sorry I don't know; why do you want lcms?

Comment: @trojanfoe to install tiff

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the source code of Libtiff in "nmake.opt"

```
#
# Uncomment and edit following lines to enable JPEG support.
#
#JPEG_SUPPORT   = 1
```

...

```
!IFDEF JPEG_SUPPORT
LIBS        = $(LIBS) $(JPEG_LIB)
EXTRAFLAGS  = -DJPEG_SUPPORT -DOJPEG_SUPPORT $(EXTRAFLAGS)
!ENDIF
```

So, by default the JPEG support not enabled.