# Old JPEG compression to New JPEG compression using libtiff

Tags: macos, jpeg, libtiff

I am currently having a problem with my tiff to bmp implementation as I always encounter this error:

scannerdata.tif: Old-style JPEG compression support is not configured.

How can I convert old-style JPEG compression to new-style JPEG compression to make it supported. Please refer to this post here for my implementation [libtiff error: Old-style JPEG compression support is not configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25359846/libtiff-error-old-style-jpeg-compression-support-is-not-configured)

Comment: Apparently the files you are working with use an obsolete form of JPEG tag. What is the source of those files?

Comment: @user3344003 those codes work in linux ubuntu and we are just trying to make it work in mac osx as well.

Comment: You probably have to (re-) compile libtiff from source, after configuring the build to include "old-style JPEG", or find another build that already has this support configured. It might be possible to convert the files to new JPEG compression, but you will need read support for "old-style JPEG" to do that... The main problem with "old-style JPEG" is that the specification isn't well-defined. You might run into images that can't be read, even if you have support enabled.